# proof of no gaps in real numbers

Tags: analysis

> **Theorem 5.5.9** (Existence of least upper bound). Let $E$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$. If E has an upper bound, (i.e., $E$ has some upper bound M), then it must have exactly one least upper bound.

> **Theorem 6.4.18** (Completeness of the reals). A sequence $(a_n)^{\infty} _{n=1}$ of
> real numbers is a Cauchy sequence if and only if it is convergent.

These two theorems  come from the textbook of Tao Analysis. And I have the following puzzle:

Suppose there is a pair of non-empty sets A and B with the properties:

$\bullet$ 1. every real number is a member of A or of B.

$\bullet$ 2. every member of A is strictly less than every member of B (and consequently no number can be a member of both).

Like in Dedekind's cut, can we call sets A and B a cut in $\mathbb R$? If yes, How can we make sure that  "**A has no largest member and B has no smallest member**" won't happen via **Theorem 5.5.9** and **Theorem 6.4.18**? Can someone give me a rigorous proof?

My rough proof is this: Suppose $x$ is the least upper bound of A, then it's also the greatest lower bound of B. Then if $x\in A$, $x$ is the largest member while B has no smallest member. If $x\in B$, $x$ is the smallest member while A has no largest member.

Sorry about this rough proof, I'm a beginner and self-taught.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Think about the least upper bound property.

Comment: I've updated, Could you help me to figure it out? @Karl

Comment: What form of completeness axiom do you use?  Both of these theorems are based on one.  Doesn't 5.5.9 answer your question?  $M$ must be a member of one set or the other.

Comment: It's not axiom, the construction of real numbers is based on Cauchy sequences. M is just an upper bound of E in theorem5.5.9 @RossMillikan

Comment: The rough proof that you added makes sense. Are you having trouble justifying part of it? Note that every element of $B$ is an upper bound of $A$, so a least upper bound of $A$ is less than or equal to every element of $B$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the proof of "Suppose x is the least upper bound of A, then it's also the greatest lower bound of B", check it out:  $SupA \le (\forall x \in B)$ $\quad$and$\quad$ $(\forall y \in A )\le SupA$. Is this enough to prove $SupA=InfB$?

Comment: I think if you use the definitions of sup and inf you'll be able to make your argument as detailed as you need to be convinced.